# Cannot print data from database using the new version

Tags: google-app-engine, web.py

I am using the latest version of web.py.

I am trying to print data from the database to a webpage.
The code i use is the following

```
import web
from google.appengine.ext import db
from models import *

urls = (
  '/', 'index',
)

render = web.template.render('templates', base='base')

class index:
    def GET(self):
        votes = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM votes")
        return render.index(votes)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
main = app.cgirun()
```

the template is the following

```
$def with(votes)


$for vote in votes:
    <li>$vote.status</li>
```

and i am getting this when i run it

```
[<models.votes object at 0x0000000004525F28>]
```

Is this a bug with the new version cause in previous version it works.

I forgot to say that i am compiling my templates as stated [here](http://webpy.org/cookbook/templates_on_gae).

Comment: Are you sure you are not shadowing the `votes` query result with the `votes` model class? Try to rename you class definiton from `votes` to `Votes`.

Comment: Yes i am sure. I renamed my class to `Votes` and i am getting the same output.

Comment: using `votes = Votes.all()` solve the problem?

Comment: where should i use that?

Comment: Replace `votes = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM votes")` with `votes = Votes.all()` and give it a try. I'm using web.py latest version too but I have no problem at all but I tend to use Class models methods and not the GqlQuery class.

Comment: Wierd, it works now. Can you give a link to read about Class models?

Comment: should work with GqlQuery too..see my answer, anyway http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on my machine, running the latest [web.py 0.36](https://github.com/webpy/webpy) with this code:

**main.py**

```
import web
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Votes(db.Model):
  status = db.StringProperty()

urls = (
  '/', 'Index',
)

render = web.template.render('templates', base='base')

class Index:
    def GET(self):
        vote = Votes()
        vote.status ="foo"
        vote.put()

        votes = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Votes")
        return render.index(votes)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
main = app.cgirun()
```

**templates/index.html**

```
$def with(votes)

$for vote in votes:
    <li>$vote.status</li>
```

**templates/base.html**

```
$def with (content)
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        $:content
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the result:

- foo

Answer (score 0):

I don't use web.py; but maybe it doesn't support generators/iterables in the templates as expected. Try fetching the results first by changing your line to:

```
votes = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM votes").fetch(100)
```